# Adding options to the Highcharts on button click

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to add scroll option after the chart is created for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: { renderTo:'chart_container' }, 

    series: [{ data: [[20, 20], [80, 80]] }]
});
```

Now a button click elsewhere in the page to add the  scrollbar option to the chart

```
scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
},
```

Comment: Highchart or Highstock ? I think the scrollbar option is only in highstock.

Comment: Sorry, there is no method in Highcharts/Highstock to update options like `scrollbar` in real time. Only solutions are: a) destroy and recreate chart b) find in sources how is scroller inited and try to implement this on your own

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollbar: {
enabled : true
}
```

This is not possible to add from out side or click.

but instead if you use highstock yes you can get a scroll bar but not like above.

you have to set min and max for xAxis. this will enable the scroll bar

here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/jKgDn/1/

hope this is useful for you

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed:

```
click() =>

   Highcharts.setOptions({scrollbar:{enabled:true}});

   var chartOptions = chart.options;

   chart.destroy();

   var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
```

where chart is the old chart without scrollbar

it works if min max defined (tx strikers)

Comment: Honestly, curious workaroung, but if works its fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as workaournd.
- enable scrollbar
- hide svg elements
- in case when you need show scrollbar, call show function on elements.

callback:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
          enableScroll(false);
      },1);

      $('#btn').click(function () {
          enableScroll(true);
      });
```

function enableScroll

```
function enableScroll(vis) { 
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        s = chart.scroller,
        showHide = vis ? 'show' : 'hide';

              s.scrollbar[showHide]();
              s.scrollbarGroup[showHide]();
              s.scrollbarRifles[showHide]();
              s.scrollbarTrack[showHide]();

              $.each(s.scrollbarButtons,function(j,elem) {
                elem[showHide]();
              });

              $.each(s.elementsToDestroy, function (i, elem) {
                    elem[showHide]();
              });

  };
```

example: 
http://jsbin.com/USOGOtu/1/